# Error while processing route Adapter operation failed Error: Adapter operation failed at new Error (native)

Tags: ember.js

While running my ember application i got an error that Error while processing route: 'posts' Adapter operation failed Error: Adapter operation failed.

Comment: Not the right kind of question for StackOverflow.

Comment: @Bhanu - it's better to give as much information you can about the problem. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34411661/ember-2-2-0-this-store-queryrecord-returns-error-adapter-operation-failed-at-ne for an example / potential solution for you.