# ember 2.2.0 this.store.queryRecord returns Error: Adapter operation failed at new Error (native) at Error.EmberError

Tags: jquery, ember.js, pouchdb

I am using ember 2.2.0 with ember-pouch, so my problem is that I am trying to retrieve data from the store by param different than id here is my code:

> this.store.queryRecord('facility', { api_number: '42-001-1234'})

and it fails it following error:

> GET http://localhost:4200/facilities?api_number=42-001-1234 404 (Not
>   Found) send @ jquery.js:9664jQuery.extend.ajax @
>   jquery.js:9215(anonymous function) @
>   rest-adapter.js:764initializePromise @ ember.debug.js:52308Promise @
>   ember.debug.js:54158ember$data$lib$system$adapter$$default.extend.ajax
>   @
>   rest-adapter.js:729ember$data$lib$system$adapter$$default.extend.queryRecord
>   @ rest-adapter.js:404ember$data$lib$system$store$finders$$_queryRecord
>   @
>   finders.js:168ember$data$lib$system$store$$Service.extend.queryRecord
>   @ store.js:897chooseFacility @
>   facility.js:16_emberMetalMixin.Mixin.create.send @
>   ember.debug.js:31366runRegisteredAction @
>   ember.debug.js:28471Backburner.run @ ember.debug.js:681run @
>   ember.debug.js:20105actions.push.handler @
>   ember.debug.js:28465(anonymous function) @
>   ember.debug.js:43052jQuery.event.dispatch @
>   jquery.js:4670elemData.handle @ jquery.js:4338 ember.debug.js:30877
>   Error: Adapter operation failed
>       at new Error (native)
>       at Error.EmberError (http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:26414:21)
>       at Error.ember$data$lib$adapters$errors$$AdapterError (http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:67497:50)
>       at ember$data$lib$system$adapter$$default.extend.handleResponse (http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:68801:16)
>       at hash.error (http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:68881:33)
>       at fire (http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:3350:30)
>       at Object.self.fireWith [as rejectWith] (http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:3462:7)
>       at done (http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:9518:14)
>       at XMLHttpRequest.callback (http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:9920:8)onerrorDefault @
>   ember.debug.js:30877exports.default.trigger @
>   ember.debug.js:52928(anonymous function) @
>   ember.debug.js:54177Queue.invoke @ ember.debug.js:320Queue.flush @
>   ember.debug.js:384DeferredActionQueues.flush @
>   ember.debug.js:185Backburner.end @ ember.debug.js:563Backburner.run @
>   ember.debug.js:685run @ ember.debug.js:20105hash.error @
>   rest-adapter.js:761fire @ jquery.js:3148self.fireWith @
>   jquery.js:3260done @ jquery.js:9316callback @ jquery.js:9718

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your problem is not on the Ember side, but in your backend. The query is correctly translated into a GET request with URL parameters, but your backend server returns a 404. If you use the returning promise, for example like this:

```
this.store.queryRecord('facility', { api_number: '42-001-1234'})
.then(function(result) {...})
.catch(function(error) {...});
```

you can handle the exception.

Comment: Thanks, you are completely right. In my case I should retrieve data from the store without making a GET request, and it is my fault, now I am using store.peekAll() and then filterBy() to retrieve the data from the store.

Comment: Tushka Dermendzhieva, if this answer helped you find the solution, go ahead and mark it as correct. @jonne - I'd love to hear you expand on why it is a problem if the server returns a 404. What is it supposed to return if the query failed?